# Angular Typescript: Unable to inject $filter in controller

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, typescript, angularjs-controller, angularjs-filter

I am using a controller inside my directive. I have declared a function (change(searchAttribute: string)) in controller constructor which will internally use the filter but i am getting runtime exception "this.$filter is not a function".

I have got many examples on google which injects $filter service the same way but i am unable to figure out why it is not working for me.

My code :

```
module app.directive {

interface MyDirectiveScope extends ng.IScope {
    myModel: any[];
    change(searchAttribute: string);
}

class MyController {
    static $inject = ['$scope', '$filter'];

    constructor(public $scope: MyDirectiveScope, public $filter: ng.IFilterService) {
        //code

        $scope.change = function (searchAttribute) {
            $scope.myModel = this.$filter('filter')($scope.myModel, searchAttribute); //error : this.$filter turns out to be undefined here
        };
    }
}

class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {

    static instance(): ng.IDirective {
        return new MyDirective;
    }

    restrict = "E";
    replace = true;
    templateUrl = "myTemplate.html";
    controller = MyController;
    scope = {};
}


angular.module("myModule")
    .directive("myDirective", MyDirective.instance);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `this` for reference constructor. But, inside an another function, `this` reference to change function and not the constructor. You need point contructor before on another variable, like `self`.

Lets go to the code:

```
constructor(public $scope: MyDirectiveScope, public $filter: ng.IFilterService) {
    let self = this;

    $scope.change = function (searchAttribute) {
        $scope.myModel = self.$filter('filter')($scope.myModel, searchAttribute);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Typescript arrow functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) to have `this` as the class instance context inside the aforesaid function:

```
$scope.change = (searchAttribute) => {
    $scope.myModel = this.$filter('filter')($scope.myModel, searchAttribute);
    // Here, this refers to your class instance context
};
```